# View Databases from android device in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sqlite

I have created a database and tables in it. Now i want to view the databases and tables from android device and not emulator in eclipse. How do i do that?

Comment: How are you going to show the db contents? Using your app or what else?

Comment: using an android application yes !!

Comment: i just want to view the contents of table that is stored in database but without using emulator

Comment: `using an android application` - So just **write the application** which reads it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Firstly you have to download SQLite browser or SQLite Manager
- Then go to DDMS in eclipse(placed on Top-Right corner)
- Then open  FileExplorer->data->data->your_project_package_name->your_database_file
  select this file and pull it out.(You can find pull out icon at top-right corner of your file explorer tab)
- Then save this file and open in SQLite browser or SQLite Manager

Comment: @vinit you got your answer..

Comment: thanks@Rahul Sharma..but i have connected my android mobile and when i click on data folder in file explorer... nothng happens..:\..Please help .

Comment: This is not what the OP asked: `i want to view the databases and tables from android device and not emulator`

Comment: i think device's database file is not easily accessible by eclipse, so its not showing, anyway be someone find my ans usefull(in case of emulator)

Comment: Thanks for ur help !! ...but rooting the mobile solve the prob ??